# PayPal Classic API - Chained Delayed and PreApproved payments?

Tags: paypal

Using the PayPal Classic API (Java) for Adaptive Payments. Is it possible to do a Chained Delayed Payment with a PreApproval? I'm getting some errors that make me think maybe it's not possible...

> Message:  Account Account not found. Unilateral receiver not allowed in chained payment is restricted

I'm getting the PreApproval just fine. But when I try to use it to make a Chained Payment it fails.

Comment: Did you make sure that " Primary and the Secondary receivers have the PayPal account " ? That will be better if you can post the correlation id that you received from PayPal in response here ?

Comment: Need to see a sample of the request and response you're getting when making the Pay call.